# Discrete Fourier Transform using WolframAlpha

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, wolfram-alpha

I tried to verify a calculation with WolframAlpha. I want to compute the DFT of $[2,3,-3,1]$. So in particular one entry of the result vector should be $2+3-3+1=3$.

I don't understand why I get {1.5+0. i, 2.5+1. i, -2.5+0. i, 2.5-1. i}. What does that mean and where is my 3?

[WolframAlpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier%5B2%2C3%2C-3%2C1%5D).

Comment: That is because Wolfram alpha uses the formula for the DFT as $X(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)e^{-j2\pi k/N}$

Comment: Thanks, so I have to multiply by $2$ in this case. But what does $0.i$ mean? Is the point supposed to be a $\cdot$?

Comment: It means that the imaginary part is $0$ which is true for the first component of the DFT here, right?

Comment: Ah, I think, it is a decimal point without any digits following.

Comment: Yeah, that could be the case since this kind of things happen when some floating point calculation produces underflow.

Comment: Do you also know how to calculate the convolution $(\sum_{i+j\equiv k\pmod n}a_ib_j)_{0\le k<n}$ of two $n$-tuples $a,b$ using WolframAlpha?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that but I am sure you can find the information easily in the web. Also, I guess you can try writing the explicit formula.

Comment: I played a little bit around with ListConvolve and found out that it looks like ListConvolve[{a,b,c,d},{w,x,y,z},1] does the job. But I don't know the meaning of the 1. Without it WolframAlpha computes only the last entry.

Answer (score 3):

That is because Wolfram alpha uses the formula for the DFT as $X(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)e^{-j2\pi k/N}$ -- [Samrat Mukhopadhyay](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240141/discrete-fourier-transform-using-wolframalpha#comment2521276_1240141)

The terms like $0.i$ appear because the coefficients are in general complex numbers, but in some of them the imaginary part is zero within machine precision. (Theoretically, it is exactly zero, but the computation uses floating point arithmetics.)